# Mail Form Sends Success Message and checks if input !empty

Tags: php, forms, email

So I am making a contact form where when we click submit, it should send an email to the admin including the inputs. the email function is already working, and what I am missing is validation to check whether input field is empty or not. I tried adding the **required** attribute in the input tag. and it works on localhost but not on the server for some reason. Also, it needs to pop up a message acknowledging that you have submitted the form. I used the **onclick** function here. but i cannot clarify whether it works, since it needs to only pop up the message when the submit is successful and there is no empty field.

Here is the code i used. connection was already established.

```
<!---Mail Starts-->
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Client<' . $_POST['mail'] . '>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['mail'] . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n";

$to = 'email@gmail.com';
$subject = "Send Us A Smile - ".$_POST['name'];
$message = "
<html>
<body>
<div style='font-family:arial;width:100%;padding:5px;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;'>
    <div style='margin:0 auto;max-width:500px;padding:5px;text-align:center;background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#741C57), to(#360d29));background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #360d29, #741C57);color:#fff;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;border-radius:15px;'>
    </div>
    <div style='text-align:center;padding:5px;color:#666;background-color:rgba(255,255,240,1);max-width:460px;margin:0 auto; border:2px solid #000;border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;'>
        <h2 style='font-weight:200;line-height:.3em;'>
            Send Us A Smile <br>
        </h2>

        <p style='text-align:left;'>
            Name : " . $_POST['name'] . "<br>
            Email : " . $_POST['mail']  . "<br>
            Subject : " . $_POST['subject'] . "<br>
            Message : " . $_POST['message'] . "
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

}
?>
<!---Mail Ends-->
<div class="full" id="contactForm">
            <div>
            <form name ="contact" action="" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="info@email.com"> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Webmail">
                        <div class="eight-eight">
                            <label class="two-eight" for="name">Name</label>
                            <input class="six-eight" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter your Name here')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="eight-eight">
                            <label class="two-eight" for="name">Subject</label>
                                <select id="subject" name="subject">
                                    <option value="">Choose  a service..</option>
<option value="">Option 1..</option>
<option value="">Option 2..</option>
                                    <option value="others">Others</option>
                                </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="eight-eight">
                            <label class="two-eight" for="name">Message</label>
                            <textarea class="six-eight" placeholder="Your message" name="message" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('May we know what your message is?')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="eight-eight">
                            <label class="two-eight" for="name">Email</label>
                            <input class="six-eight" type="mail" name="mail" placeholder="Your email address" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter your Email Address here')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>
                        </div>

                        <input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Send" onclick="hgsubmit()">
                        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.email.com"> 
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Is there a different way to do it?

Comment: There are certainly ways to do any of this, but it's going to involve some coding on your part.  For the validation, you can't implicitly trust client-side validation.  You would want to include server-side code to check if the values were submitted.  For example, you currently check `isset($_POST['submit'])` to see if the form was posted at all.  You can perform similar checks to see if specific data elements were posted in the form, you can check the length of posted strings, etc.  Build your logic to perform your checks and send or not send the message accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a validator I use as part of my in house development tool. it is a server side, and part of a larger framework, but it will be ok for you.

```
    <?php

/*
 *
 * @Class Name:InputValidation
 * @Framework:Mlisoft MLM 4.0
 * @Date Created: 18, August, 2017
 * @Version: 1.0
 * @Contributor: Adeniyi Anthony A <a.anthony@mlisoftinc.com>
 * @mlisoftinc@gmail.com
 *
 */

class InputValidation
{
    /*
     * ----------------------------------------------------------------
     * Validate form input
     * ----------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    /*
     * Validate form input
     * @param   array    $data
     * @param   array    $exceptionList
     * @param   array    $alias
     * @param   array    $filters
     * @return  array
    */
    public function validateInputs(array $data, array $exceptionList = null, array $alias = null, array $filters = null)
    {
        if ($data == null || $data == "" || !$data || !is_array($data)) {
            return array(
                'status' => false,
                'msg' => 'Invalid data provided',
            );
        }
        $errorList = null;
        foreach ($data as $curData => $value) {
            $exceptCurrent = false;

            if ($value == "") {
                /*
                 * check if this is part of the exception
                 */
                if ($exceptionList !== null) {
                    foreach ($exceptionList as $curExcept) {
                        /*
                         * case insensitive search
                         */
                        if ($curData == $curExcept) {
                            $exceptCurrent = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if ($exceptCurrent === false) {
                    if ($alias != null && isset($alias[$curData])) {
                        $name = $alias[$curData];
                    } else {
                        $name = $curData;
                    }
                    $errorList[] = array(
                        'name' => $name,
                        'value' => $value,
                    );
                }
            }

            /*
             * finally, lets validate filters if they are passed
             */
            if ($filters != null && isset($filters[$curData])) {
                /*
                 * check the filter validations
                 */
                $curFilter = $filters[$curData];
                /*
                 * go over the filter, and validate each filter
                 * parameter provided
                 */
                foreach ($curFilter as $key => $paramValue) {
                    if (!isset($name)) {
                        $name = $curData;
                    }

                    if ($key == "must") {
                        /*
                         * validate must contain the exact value provided
                         * can use regular expression later
                         */
                        if (!preg_match("/" . $paramValue . "/", $value)) {
                            $msg = "value must contain $paramValue";
                            $errorList[] = array(
                                'name' => $name,
                                'value' => $value,
                                'msg' => $msg,
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /*
         * attempt tp build a long error message
         */
        $msg = null;
        if (isset($errorList) && $errorList !== null) {
            $msg = "Invalid input. Ensure all required form field are entered<br>";
            foreach ($errorList as $error) {
                if (isset($error['msg'])) {
                    $msg = $msg . $error['name'] . " " . $error['msg'];
                } else {
                    $msg = $msg . $error['name'] . " cannot be empty<br>";
                }
            }
        }
        /*
         * return complete validation
         */
        if ($errorList === null) {
            return array(
                'status' => true,
                'msg' => 'Success',
                'error' => false,
                'error_list' => $errorList,
                'error_msg' => null,
            );
        } elseif ($errorList !== null) {
            return array(
                'status' => false,
                'msg' => 'Failed',
                'error' => true,
                'error_list' => $errorList,
                'error_msg' => $msg,
            );
        }
    }

}
```

call validation like this:

```
$validator = new InputValidation();
        $val = $validator->validateInputs($data);

        if (isset($val['error']) && $val['error'] == true) {
            // do whatever
            );
        }
```

The validator also accept other optional parameters like

$exceptionList   ['formField','anotherFormFiled']
   use to exempt some field from validation

$alias   pass as array('formField' => 'Form Filed Caption')
   use to display custom some field caption

$filters as ['email' => array('must' => "@")]
  use to validate input. for example email